# Determine and sketch the set of pairs $(x,y)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Determine and sketch the set of pairs $(x, y)$ in
$\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}.$
that satisfy:

(a) $|x| = |y|$

(b) $|x| + |y| = 1$

(c) $|xy| = 2$

(d) $|x| - |y| = 2$

Comment: Welcome! Kindly show attempt and add context.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy.
**For part (a)**, if you have $|x| = |y|$ then it shows line $x = y$ or $x=-y$.

**For part (b)**, if you have $|x| + |y| = 1$, basically you have a region with 4 boundaries. The equation of the boundaries are $x + y = 1$, $x-y = 1$, $-x+y=1$, and $-x-y=1$. Pay attention for the quadrant.
Usually this is known as **taxicab norm** or $\ell_1$ norm.

**For part (c)**, if you have $|xy| = 2$, you will have $|x||y|=2$.
Try to draw $y = \frac{2}{x}$, and then reflect that graph over $y-$ axis and $x-$ axis, from the first quadrant until foruth quadrant.

**For part (d)**, you have 4 line equation. That is $x-y = 2$ on the 1st quadrant, $x+y=2$ on the 4th quadrant, $-x-y=2$ on the 2nd quadrant, $-x+y=2$ on the 3rd quadrant.

You can use desmos.com to draw your graph.

Comment: For part (d), $|x| = |y| + 2 \implies |x| \geq 2$.  That said, please do not answer questions that do not meet [quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).